# Start JBoss EAP server with paused queue

Tags: java, jboss, jms, hornetq, message-driven-bean

I have implemented a JMS based application relying on JBoss EAP 6.3 HornetQ. I have several queues, but I need one of them to be "paused" by default (at server startup), unless I explicitly resume it.

If you are wondering why I need a paused queue, it's because it is a "resubmission" dead letter queue:

1. When I'm unable to deliver a message, I queue it in the DLQ for future resubmission.
2. Monitoring that queue, I notice that the resubmission queue is filling, so I inspect and fix the cause.
3. Once fixed, I resume the resubmission queue: an MDB properly (with some logic) resubmits each message to the queue it came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe HornetQ has the ability you're looking for.  However, this ability was added to ActiveMQ Artemis (the project to which HornetQ was donated) in version 1.5 via [ARTEMIS-753](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-753). You'd need to migrate to a later version of JBoss EAP which uses Artemis 1.5 (or later) as the JMS implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately our corporate cannot upgrade to EAP 7. @justin Do you have any suggestion to workaround the lack of this feature?

Comment: You could theoretically take the fix from ARTEMIS-753 and backport it to HornetQ on your own branch.  It's all open source.